# How to create a generalized dataset to detect all display digits with Roboflow

Tags: digits, yolov5, roboflow

I want to detect digits on a display. For doing that I am using a custom 19 classes dataset. The choosen model has been yolov5-X. The resolution is 640x640. Some of the objets are:

- 0-9 digits
- Some text as objects
- Total -->  17 classes

I am having problems to detect all the digits when I want to detect 23, 28, 22 for example. If they are very close to each other the model finds problems.

I am using roboflow to create diferent folders in which I add some prepcocessings to have a full control of what I am entering into the model. All are checked and entered in a new folder called TRAIN_BASE.  In total I have 3500 images with digits and the majority of variance is with hue and brightness.

Any advice to make the model able to catch all the digits besides being to close from each other?

Comment: Could you post some examples of the bad detections? I can give some suggestions for improvement but it depends on what they look like

Comment: @BradDwyer, due to enterprise privacy reasons I can´t share the images of the display. However, I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I follow:

- First of all, The use of mosaic dataset was not a good choice the purpose of detecting digits on a display because in a real scenario I was never gonna find pieces of digits. That reason made the model not to recognize some digits if it was not shure.

  [example of the digits problem concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmuMD.png)
- Another big improvement was to [change the anchor boxes](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/2092) of the yolo model to adapt them to small objects. To know which anchor boxes I needed. Just with adding [this argument](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/607) to train.py is enought in the script provided by ultralitics to print custom anchors and add them to your custom architecture.
- To check which augmentations can be good and which not, [the next article](https://blog.roboflow.com/yolov4-data-augmentation/) explains it quite visually.

P.D: *Thanks for the fast response to help the comunity gave me.*